# How to pass the captured image to a different activity to set to the image view in android and store in a databse

Tags: android

Can anybody tell how to pass the captured image to a different activity to set the image view in android and store in a database? Can anybody provide code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

1.Capture and get the bitmap of the captured image in the onActivityResult()

```
public void capture(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        }
    }
}
```

2 Send the Image to the next Activity...You can send the Bitmap because it implements Parcelable

```
private void sendImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("image", thumbnail);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

3 Get the image in the NextActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap) extras.get("image");
    if (image != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow these steps :-

1. capture image using camera
2. save this image
3. get the file URI
4. In your next activity you can show this image using that file URI

let me know if you have any issue.

To Save your bitmap in sdcard use the following code

Store Image

```
private void storeImage(Bitmap image) {
    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");// e.getMessage());
        return;
    } 
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }  
}
```

To Get the Path for Image Storage

```
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this. 
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files"); 

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    } 
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
        String mImageName="MI_"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);  
    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: first try there are so many tutorials. read them we are not here to code for you, we can help you only so try your best first.